# Installing ffmpeg-php on Media Temple Server

Tags: linux, mediatemple, configuration

migrating a Plesk server from 3.5 to 4.0 and reinstalling some apps we use (Tomcat, ffmpeg, etc.). Got all those installed fine, but following the instructions for installing ffmpeg-php (from here: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv):Installing_FFmpeg_and_FFmpeg-php), I'm getting an error when I go to `./configure && make`

These are the errors I'm seeing:

```
/root/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_frame.c: In function 'zim_ffmpeg_frame_ffmpeg_frame':
/root/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_frame.c:432: error: 'PIX_FMTRGB32' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_frame.c:432: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/root/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_frame.c:432: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a typo. When changing references in ffmpeg_frame.c, I must have got rid of a underscore accidentally. It should be "PIX_FMT_RBG32" and not "PIX_FMTRGB32."